# Errors in Golang - assessing errors

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the following example

https://gobyexample.com/errors

I understand most of it except for this part:

```
_, e := f2(42)
if ae, ok := e.(*argError); ok {
    fmt.Println(ae.arg)
    fmt.Println(ae.prob)
}
```

I'm not sure what this line does :

```
if ae, ok := e.(*argError); ok {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
e.(*argError)
```

is a type assertion that casts the value e to *argError type.  This is the type f2() returns on error - it is a pointer to an argError struct, which implements the error interface. This type assertion evaluates multi-valued to (ae,ok), where ae is the *argError typed value, if successful, and ok is a boolean letting you know if it was successful.

if statements in go can be separated into an initial assignment part, then a semicolon, then a boolean condition to evaluate to determine the branch.

Altogether, then,

```
if ae, ok := e.(*argError); ok {
```

means:  try to cast e to *argError, if that is successful (do if block).

Why do this?   Because argError has fields that are not in a plain error (arg, prob), and you might want to use those.  In real code where you do this, you'd likely also need to handle the case where e was not an argError, but some other error type, in an "else" branch.

Answer (score 0):

Add Go official link here on ['Type assertions'](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15):

A type assertion provides access to an interface value's underlying concrete value.

```
t := i.(T)
```

This statement asserts that the interface value i holds the concrete type T and assigns the underlying T value to the variable t.

If i does not hold a T, the statement will trigger a panic.

To test whether an interface value holds a specific type, a type assertion can return two values: the underlying value and a boolean value that reports whether the assertion succeeded.

```
t, ok := i.(T)
```

If i holds a T, then t will be the underlying value and ok will be true.

If not, ok will be false and t will be the zero value of type T, and no panic occurs.

Note the similarity between this syntax and that of reading from a map.